# Parameter being optional or not, depending on previous parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have two methods:

```
Foo(int a, bool useDb)
Foo(int a, bool useDb, DbContext dbContext)
```

Is there a way to make it as ONE method, with those rules?
if `useDb` is true `dbContext` is mandatory
if `useDb` is false `dbContext` is optional

**EDIT:**

Just an edit to clarify, what I'm trying to do:
In Business/Service layer, I have `ItemService` with method `GetItemStatus`. It connects to the database, get data and calculate the status.

There's nothing special. It creates a DbContext (EF6.0), do the thing and dispose it. Standard. But what if I want to use GetItemStatus as a part of different transaction? Ha!? I need to pass DbContext inside and do not dispose it obviously. I created something like this:

```
    public ItemStatus GetItemStatus(int itemId, OfficeContext fni = null)
    {
        bool shouldBeDisposed = (fni == null) ? true : false;
        if (shouldBeDisposed) fni = ContextFactory.CreateOfficeContext();

        try
        {

            Do the stuff...

        }
        finally
        {
            if (shouldBeDisposed) fni?.Dispose();
        }

        return ...
    }
```

But now I'm a little bit afraid, because if someone calls:

`GetItemStatus(123456);`

... and he forgot to add DbContext. I'm not sure if he actually means it. Altoguh it shouldn't be that bad. He will create new one and dispose it.

But I was thinking of the best way, to be sure that developer will not make a mistake. The "foolproof" way.

Comment: The way you are trying to do it is wrong practice. I guess you don't need useDb at all. If the caller thinks it needs to provide db then it will anyway.

Comment: Robert C Martin mentions this in his book clean code. Having boolean arguments declare that the method you are calling does more than one thing. Martin Fowler has an interesting article on the subject, it is better to have a well named method than to use flags. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html

Comment: @EmmaMiddlebrook I edited my question. Do you think I should have two functions? `GetItemStatus` and `GetItemStatusWithContext`?

Comment: @Marshall - yes exactly, much clearer and cleaner code. Will be easier to unit test in isolation as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to enforce a *situationally* optional parameter.

You can still make it an optional parameter and then manually throw an exception if the needed parameter was not supplied.

```
public void Foo(int a, bool useDB, DbContext dbContext = null)
{
    if(useDB && dbContext == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("DB context must be supplied!");
    }

    //...
}
```

However, this will cause exceptions at runtime, and will not warn you at compile time. You'll end up having to bugfix the previously omitted db context, which is not the preferred approach.

---

I wonder what the need for the `useDB` boolean is. You can already derive that from whether a context was passed or not:

```
public void Foo(int a, DbContext dbContext)
{
    //you already know useDB == true
}

public void Foo(int a)
{
    //you already know useDB == false
}
```

This can also be put into a single method by making the dbcontext an optional parameter:

```
public void Foo(int a, DbContext dbContext = null)
{
    bool useDB = (dbContext != null);
}
```

This seems like a much cleaner approach. You omit a redundant parameter (`useDB`), which in turn forgoes the need for enforcing a situationally optional parameter.
Whoever uses the method will simply have to provide a db context if they want it to be used.

Comment: I edited my question. `useDB` is not needed. It's the parameter to double check if developer knows what he/she is doing. Does it smell?

Comment: @Marshall: **(1)** If someone forgets to add the dbcontext parameter, that is **their** mistake. Your boolean parameter is not going to stop mistakes from happening. It's creating an obstacle for _everyone_ just in case someone forgets something. It's a bigger hassle than it is a solution. **(2)** `(fni == null) ? true : false` can be shortened to `(fni == null)` **(3)** Personally, I would wrap the method. The outer method adds your context if needed, calls the inner method, and then disposes the context (if it's yours). The inner method handles the db regardless of where you got the context.

Comment: @Marshall: But such a discussion is better had in a new question on CodeReview.SE :)

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Maybe I will post a question on CodeReview later today

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make a single function signature do that in C#. Closest you can achieve is with overloading

```
public Foo(int a) { Foo(a, false, null); }
public Foo(int a, DbContext dbContext){ Foo(a, true, dbContext); }
private Foo(int a, bool useDb, DbContext dbContext){ ... }
```

The overload with all arguments can be private so it's not invoked with invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is just a matter of how you do it.

this would be one solution:

```
Public void Foo(int a, bool useDB, DbContext dbContext)
{
   if(useDb)
   {
       //use the database
   }
   else
   {
      //do whatever you would otherwise do.
   }
}
```

Then, when you go to call the method, here are the two options:

```
Foo(1, true, db); //calls Foo with useDB and a dbContext

Foo(1, false, null); //calls Foo with useDB false and null dbContext
```

Comment: You can also add additional checks to make sure that if useDB is true, dbContext is not null

Comment: Like I commented before. I edited my question. `useDB` is the parameter to double check if developer knows what he/she is doing. Does it smell? Look at my edit

Comment: So you're trying to fix an issue because you think the developers are going t be idiots.  This is not the way to do it.  Either create the context yourself, and don't even worry about them trying to pass one. Or only allow them to pass the context, and return null if they screw it up.  A null result to their query will tell them, pretty decisively, they did something wrong.  You could also throw an error to them.